# Joomla 2.5: install K2 manually?

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5, joomla-k2

I am having all sorts of problems installing the K2 component with Joomla 2.5.

If I do a regular install, I get the message:

```
JFolder::create: could not create directory
```

even though all my folder permissions are ok.

If I try to Install from a Directory I get:

```
JInstaller::install: Cannot find XML setup file
```

I searched the structure of K2 and it does not have a `setup.xml` file.

Can anyone point me in the right direction? Thanks

Comment: go to your Joomla backend and then go to `Help >> System Information >> Directory Permissions` and make sure all the folder mentioned are "writable"

Comment: May I also add that I had this problem once and it may be due to the fact that your FTP account doesn't have ownership of the directories, even though they are set o 777

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have a server configuration issue. You will most likely need to enable the FTP layer to get it to work. If I were you I would switch to a host that specializes in Joomla like Rochen.